# How to convert −0 to string with sign preserved?

Tags: javascript, negative-zero

```
x = -0
>> -0
typeof(x)
>> "number"
x.toString()
>> "0"
console.log(x)
>> -0
```

How can I convert Javascript's −0 (number zero with the sign bit set rather than clear) to a two character string (`"-0"`) in the same way that `console.log` does before displaying it?

Comment: Is this Node.js or no? What kind of compatibility do you need?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If Node.js (or [npm available](https://www.npmjs.com/package/util-inspect)¹) `util.inspect` will do that:

```
> util.inspect(-0)
'-0'
```

If not, you can make a function:

```
const numberToString = x =>
    Object.is(x, -0) ?
        '-0' :
        String(x);
```

Substitute the condition with `x === 0 && 1 / x === -Infinity` if you don’t have `Object.is`.

<sub>¹ I haven’t read this package’s source and it could be updated in the future anyway; look at it before installing!</sub>

Answer (score 2):

How about this (idea borrowed from [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_zero#Comparisons)):

```
[-0, 0].forEach(function(x){
    console.log(x, x === 0 && 1/x === -Infinity ? "-0" : "0");
});
```

Comment: `1 / x === -Infinity` isn’t enough, as it’s true for `x = -1e-309` though `-1e-309 !== 0`.

Answer (score 0):

[As per specification](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/index.html#sec-tostring-applied-to-the-number-type), -0 is the only number which `Number(String(x))` do not generate the original value of `x`.

Sadly, all stander `toString` method tell `-0` just like `0`. Which convert to string `'0'` instead of `'-0'`.

You may be interested in function [`uneval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/uneval) on Firefox. But since its Firefox only, non-standard feature. You should avoid using it on website. (Also, never do `eval(uneval(x))` as deep clone please)

Maybe you have to do this with your own codes:

```
function numberToString(x) {
  if (1 / x === -Infinity && x === 0) return '-0';
  return '' + x;
}
```

Comment: `1 / x === -Infinity` isn’t enough, as it’s true for `x = -1e-309` though `-1e-309 !== 0`.

Comment: I just wrote up your comment as an answer, but as you have done the same, I just removed mine. Thanks for `uneval`.

Comment: @user3070485: … you needed it in Firefox/js* only?

Comment: @Ryan ok, fixed.

Answer (score -1):

So cant we simply get the sign of -0 it's unique and -0 if sign is -0 we can append '-' to zero.Any thoughts

Comment: Math.sign(0) and Math.sign(-0) are both 0. The Math.sign() of non-zero numbers are +1 or -1. Maybe you have another way of getting the sign?

Comment: Nope Math.sign(-0) = -0

Comment: had a look at it again.Check this doc of MSDN also it says Math.sign(-0) = -0 and also Math.sign(+0) = +0 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/scripting/javascript/reference/math-sign-function-javascript

Comment: Okay. The problem is then still the same though: "how to test for -0". 0 and -0 look the same much of the time, for example -0==0 and -0===0. So applying Math.sign() to 0 and -0 doesn't help because it doesn't do anything -- you just get the same out as you put in!